# On the space of Carleson measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Consider the space $X=\mathcal{CM}(\mathbb{D})$ of finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{D}$ whose total variation is a Carleson measure. It is easy to see that this space is a vector space. Moreover, given $\mu\in X$ we can define $\|\mu\|:=B(|\mu|)$, where $$B(|\mu|):=
\sup_{z_0\in \mathbb{D}}\int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{1-|z_0|^2}{|1-\overline{z}_0z|^2}\text{d}|\mu|(z)$$

with this norm equipped, the space is a Banach space. Now, Carleson measures are important for many different reasons, so it is normal to try and study the banach space properties of this space. However, I have not been able to find any reference on this problem.

in brief, my question is:
What is known about the Banach space properties of this space?

Any reference is welcome.